# Is there a way for a Power BI custom visual to get the report ID, dataset ID, and workspace ID?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to see if it's possible to build a context-aware Power BI custom visual, one in which I can detect (at render-time) the IDs of the report, dataset, and workspace in which the visual is being run. I haven't found anything in [the API's TypeScript definitions](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-visuals-api), nor in [the Power BI visuals documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/). Any tips or tricks that anyone is aware of? I'm considering experimenting with accessing `window.parent.location` or `document.referrer`...?